# How to redirect user to root route if the user refreshes the page on any other route in REACT ROUTER?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So, in my project I have two routes one is the root route and other is the `/game` route. And I always
want the user to start from the root route because the user needs to set a **mandatory state variable** before moving to `/game` route.

But if the user refreshes the page on game route I want to redirect to root route. So all I want is that the entry point to my application is always the root route.

```
        <Router>
          <Route path="/">
            <Redirect to="/" />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home setLevel={setLevel} />}></Route>
          <Route exact path="/game" render={() => <Game level={level} />}></Route>
        </Router>
```

The setup above works on `localhost` but when I deploy my app on Netlify it doesn't work. So if the user refreshes the page on `/game` route, it says page not found.

Here's full code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Redirect,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

const Home = ({ setLevel }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Choose Difficulty</h1>
      <ul>
        <li onClick={() => setLevel("easy")}>Easy</li>
        <li onClick={() => setLevel("hard")}>Hard</li>
      </ul>
      <Link to="/game">Play</Link>
    </>
  );
};

const Game = ({ level }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Welcome to the game</h1>
      <p>Your level is {level}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(null);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/">
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home setLevel={setLevel} />}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/game" render={() => <Game level={level} />}></Route>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't investigated your React set up too closely, but you may just be missing a `_redirects` file for your Netflify deployment: https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-redirects-file

`react-router-dom` is a client side router, so when Netlify loads a page using server side rendering (aka, when you refresh or visit a page for the first time, that is not a client side redirect), it cannot find the route on the server. Adding a `_redirects` file will instruct Netlify how to serve up your pages on initial load.

Comment: Are you able to share your working app in a code sandbox? I'm trying to investigate your set up, but can't get the app to render. Feel free to edit/fork this one I started: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-bb95k?file=/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when the user refreshes the page, state `level` becomes `null` again.
Then update your code as below:

```
const Game = ({ level }) => {
  // add a guard right here
  if (!level) {
    return <Redirect to="/"/>;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Welcome to the game</h1>
      <p>Your level is {level}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(null);
  return (
    <Router>
      { /* remove this code
      * <Route path="/">
      * <Redirect to="/" />
      * </Route>
      */ }
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home setLevel={setLevel} />}></Route>
      <Route exact path="/game" render={() => <Game level={level} />}></Route>
    </Router>
  );
};
```